# How to monitor an OpenVPN connection

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I'm connecting to VPN service via the command line:

```
sudo openvpn --config-file <.....> --auth-user-pass <.....>
```

But in doing so I don't have a convenient way to monitor the connection. Specifically, I'd like some way to easily verify that my VPN is connected and maybe even lock outgoing traffic if OpenVPN dies.

I can't do this through the network manager because DNS is leaking and network-manager is apparently the problem, and I can't use the provider's Linux app because it apparently inserts ip routes that screw with Docker and Docker-Compose.

Any help at all would be appreciated.

On Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an app to communicate with OpenVPN process via the management interface.

Here is the link to [OpenVPN management interface](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/79-management-interface.html).

Comment: welp. Guess that's what I gotta do then :-|